# Paginate Instagram with ajax into a table

Tags: php, ajax, json, instagram, instagram-api

I need to hit the Instagram API with an ajax request to get the next batch of photos and data (Instagram API limits to 20 photos per request), and load it onto the same html page, specifically into a table. **I am stuck at AJAX...**

I've got this PHP and HTML working. I am also able to paginate, just not by ajax which (I think) is what I need...

Using user_id, get photos, likes, from past 30 days:

```
if (!empty($_GET['user_id'])){
    $user_id = ($_GET['user_id']);
    $min_timestamp = strtotime('-30 days',time());
    $next_max_id = $_GET['next_max_id'];
    $instagram_url  = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' . $user_id . '/media/recent/?client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID}&min_timestamp=' . $min_timestamp;
    // if($next_max_id != "")
    $instagram_url  .= "&max_id=" . $next_max_id;
    $instagram_json  = file_get_contents($instagram_url);
    $instagram_array  = json_decode($instagram_json ,true);
    }}
```

Put it into a table (so I can sort by likes it with bootstrap-table-sort):

```
if(!empty($instagram_array)){
  foreach($instagram_array['data'] as $image){
    echo 
      '<tr>
        <td>' . date('M d, Y', $image['created_time']) . '</td>
        <td>'.$image['likes']['count'].'</td>
        <td class="text-right"><img src="'.$image['images']['standard_resolution']['url'].'" alt=""/ style="max-height:40px"></td>
        </tr>';
  }}
```

Paginate - *via new page refresh (boo!)* - needs to be via ajax!

```
<? if( $instagram_array['pagination']['next_max_id'] != "" ): ?>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="?user_id=<?=$user_id?>&next_max_id=<?=$instagram_array['pagination']['next_max_id']?>">More...</a>
<? endif;?>
```

How can I get an AJAX request to load next images? I really hope I don't have to redo all my markup and throw away this php, but if it's best, I'll do what I have to do:)

ps - I know nothing about ajax, so please forgive my need for hand-holding:(

Comment: Basically, AJAX is just the name for making HTTP requests from Javascript. In PHP, you might be interested in using a library like curl.

Comment: Interesting ok... Could you point me in the right direction within curl?